# Can matrices with dependent columns being QR factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem comes from the $18.06$ Linear Algebra by MIT Open Courseware.

[image: Question]

The answer:
[image: Answer]

I am very confused. According to the definition, [image]

Matrix A -> QR means that A has independent columns. BUT it is obviously that the matrix B is singular in the problem. But it can be diagnoalized with 3 independent eigenvectors. How could that happen? Could you explain ?

Thanks!

Comment: $R$ need not be invertible.

Comment: I got this exact same question at the exact same problem set & same step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $A$ is singular, it can still exhibit a $QR$ decomposition, the trade off is $R$ is singular as well. Some of the diagonal entries are $0$.

Also, any symmetrical matrices can be diagonalized. Being singular means that some of the eigenvalues are $0$.

Comment: Er. So any matrix can exhibit QR factorization? There is no requirement in QR factorization?

Comment: Yes, any square matrices exhibit QR factorization.